# Having trouble implementing updateSearchResultsForSearchController in UISearchController?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I'm having a difficult time trying to implement `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` in a `UISearchController`. It has to do with how I implemented my original array. I'm not sure how to use that array to find the searched text.

Here's a snippet of my code:

Test.swift:

```
struct Test
{
    let name: String
    let hobby: String
}
```

Main.swift:

```
var resultsSearchController = UISearchController()
var filteredData: [Test] = [Test]()

var data: [Test] = [Test]()

override func viewDidLoad()
{        
    resultsSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    definesPresentationContext = true
    resultsSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    resultsSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    tableView.tableHeaderView = resultsSearchController.searchBar

    data = [
    Test(name: "Abby", hobby: "Games"),
    Test(name: "Brian", hobby: "TV"),
    Test(name: "Ced", hobby: "Gym"),
    Test(name: "David", hobby: "Fun")]

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if (resultsSearchController.active && resultsSearchController.searchBar.text != "")
    {
        return filteredData.count
    }

    return data.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell: UITableViewCell!

    // Dequeue the cell to load data
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Funny", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let example: Test

    if resultsSearchController.active && resultsSearchController.searchBar.text != ""
    {
        example = filteredData[indexPath.row]
    }
    else
    {
        example = data[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    filteredData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "hobby CONTAINS[c] %@", resultsSearchController.searchBar.text!)

    // WHAT ELSE TO DO?

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I'm just a bit confused on how to use my `data` to return back the correct searched results in `updateSearchResultsForSearchController`.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you need to to is make the search in your data source and return the data nothing else, something like this code:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    filteredData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchedData = resultsSearchController.searchBar.text

    // find elements that contains the searchedData string for example
    filteredData = data.filter { $0.name.containsString(searchedData) }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

If you want to perform another type of search regarding another field of your `struct` you can modify the `filter` like you like. Once you call the `tableView.reloadData()` all is going to be reloaded again.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you it does help. However, I'm facing one last issue. `resultsSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true` dims my background when the search is present, which is what I like...However, I can't select the filtered results and instead, it goes back to the original Table View. Setting `resultsSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false` works, but I'd like to dim the background when searching is present. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `UISearchController` will dim the view it is presented over. This is useful if you are using another view controller for searchResultsController, in your case you're using the same `UITableViewController` isn't?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I am using same Table View. I just want to dim the background. Would the only way to accomplish this is to create a `UIView` overlay when search is present and dim its background? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: The problem is that if you dim the background you cannot interact with the results, it block it, it's the default behaviour, you can simulate it as you said using a `UIView` overlay, it can be a solution easy to implement